# Is it possible to sync a different iCloud accounts data using Core Data on Device?

Tags: ios, core-data, cloudkit

I'm developing an app using Core Data and CloudKit. Everything works great, but I'm wondering if it's possible to sync the core data entities from a different iCloud user to the application? What I mean in detail is:

- currently the app doesn't require some sort of authentication because core data automatically attaches the records to the signed-in Apple-Id of the devices user
- I would like to add some sort of authentication to the app to use as the personal key for the CloudKit records to get used for
- therefore it would be possible to sign in with a different Apple-ID for the application and those entities get synced, not the entities from the devices apple-id

It seams like that this wouldn't be able to accomplish using core data on its own, but I'm wondering as well if it's necessary to have some sort of authentication for the app if everything is already bound to the device apple-Id?

The single advantage an authentication would have is, that I could get the users email for some sort of newsletter I guess?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. There is no API for CloudKit that lets you connect to an account different from the account currently associated with the device.

A user would need to logout of their current Apple ID on their device and then log into the other account. Of course this affects the whole device and a lot of data. This is not something someone would want to do just to use one app.

The closest you can get is to make use of a user's shared database. If user A grants shared access to a record zone or a specific hierarchy of data from their private database to some user B, then user B can access that shared data from user A. All of that sharing would need to be features provided by your app. But it does require that user A must initiate the sharing on their own device and then user B can accept the share on their own device.

Comment: Thank you very much vor the clarification. It's the first project where I'm using CloudKit. How is it related to support cases? Let's say after an app update a user has problems with corrupt data. When thinking of a solution like realm, it would be possible to fix those entities in the database if there was a problem with migrating. Is there a way to do this with CloudKit as well? Or how could I give an user support in some kind of similar situations?

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand your comment. It sounds like a whole new question. But I can say that you, as the developer, have no access to users' private or shared databases.